# Problem with displaying icons in Angular-material

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6, angular-material-6, angular-material-7

I have a problem with angular icons, all my browsers are not able to show icons, I tried to reinstall my Chrome, but it was no result, neither my project's icons nor icons of material.angular.io are shown, but on phone all is ok

here are my screens from pc:

`<mat-icon matBadge="{{service.cart.length}}">add_shopping_cart</mat-icon>`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
and this is screen from my phone:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: in developer tools, do you see icons loaded? any 404 there?

Comment: @Akber Iqbal, yes there was some errors of that kind, I changed all my icons to google icons now all is working normal, only using mat-icons is problem